# Hystrix Dashboard with Turbine issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, turbine

I have multiple service that are mapped thru zuul so my turbine project looks for hystrix.stream from the zuul project.

I think i have setup everyting right because I can see the hits getting updated properly. But the below section for Thread Pools keeps on loading what am i missing here and whats the use of it,  couldnot find anything that can help me to understand it actual use.Here is the screenshot of my dahsboard. 
 [Hystrix Dashboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCStW.png)

Let me know if more info is needed for the same.

Comment: is there an error in your browser javascript console?

Comment: @spencergibb sorry about the late response was out on vacation. There are no errors on the js console.