# Zuul defaulting hystrix isolation strategy to SEMAPHORE

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, hystrix, netflix-zuul, turbine

This is in continuation to my previous question where in my hystrix dashboard the Thread Pool section keeps on loading:- [Hystrix Dashboard with Turbine issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444958/hystrix-dashboard-with-turbine-issue)

Why is zuul forcing the isolation strategy for hystrix to be SEMAPHORE. I tried adding the configuration to my application.yml but still it ignores that and uses SEMAPHORE. Is there something that I am missing here. Or how would i change it from SEMAPHORE to THREAD.

Application.yml

```
info:
  component: Zuul Server

eureka:
 client:
   service-url: 
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false

server:
  port: 8006

zuul:
  routes:
    UserCards-V1: 
         path: /user/v1/accountholders/*/cards/**
         service-id: usercards-v1
         strip-prefix: false
    UserTransactions-V1_1: 
         path: /user/v1/accountholders/*/transactions
         service-id: usertransactions-v1
         strip-prefix: false
    UserTransactions-V1_2:  
         path: /user/v1/accountholders/*/accounts/*/transactions
         service-id: usertransactions-v1
         strip-prefix: false
    UserAccounts-V1: 
         path: /user/v1/accountholders/*/accounts/**
         service-id: useraccounts-v1
         strip-prefix: false
    UserCardholders-V1: 
         path: /user/v1/accountholders/**
         service-id: usercardholders-v1
         strip-prefix: false 

hystrix: 
  command.default.execution.isolation.strategy: THREAD
  command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
  command.default.execution.timeout.enabled: false
  command.default.fallback.enabled: false
  threadpool.default.coreSize: 20


ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 3000
  ReadTimeout: 60000

turbine: 
   clusterNameExpression: zuul
```

Hystrix.stream

```
data: {"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"usercardholders-v1RibbonCommand","group":"RibbonCommand","currentTime":1451411772021,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":0,"rollingCountBadRequests":0,"rollingCountCollapsedRequests":0,"rollingCountEmit":0,"rollingCountExceptionsThrown":0,"rollingCountFailure":0,"rollingCountEmit":0,"rollingCountFallbackFailure":0,"rollingCountFallbackRejection":0,"rollingCountFallbackSuccess":0,"rollingCountResponsesFromCache":0,"rollingCountSemaphoreRejected":0,"rollingCountShortCircuited":0,"rollingCountSuccess":0,"rollingCountThreadPoolRejected":0,"rollingCountTimeout":0,"currentConcurrentExecutionCount":0,"rollingMaxConcurrentExecutionCount":0,"latencyExecute_mean":0,"latencyExecute":{"0":0,"25":0,"50":0,"75":0,"90":0,"95":0,"99":0,"99.5":0,"100":0},"latencyTotal_mean":0,"latencyTotal":{"0":0,"25":0,"50":0,"75":0,"90":0,"95":0,"99":0,"99.5":0,"100":0},"propertyValue_circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold":20,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds":5000,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage":50,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceOpen":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceClosed":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerEnabled":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationStrategy":"SEMAPHORE","propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds":60000,"propertyValue_executionTimeoutInMilliseconds":60000,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadInterruptOnTimeout":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadPoolKeyOverride":null,"propertyValue_executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":100,"propertyValue_fallbackIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,"propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,"propertyValue_requestCacheEnabled":true,"propertyValue_requestLogEnabled":true,"reportingHosts":1,"threadPool":"RibbonCommand"}

data: {"type":"HystrixCommand","name":"usercards-v1RibbonCommand","group":"RibbonCommand","currentTime":1451411772522,"isCircuitBreakerOpen":false,"errorPercentage":0,"errorCount":0,"requestCount":1,"rollingCountBadRequests":0,"rollingCountCollapsedRequests":0,"rollingCountEmit":0,"rollingCountExceptionsThrown":0,"rollingCountFailure":0,"rollingCountEmit":0,"rollingCountFallbackFailure":0,"rollingCountFallbackRejection":0,"rollingCountFallbackSuccess":0,"rollingCountResponsesFromCache":0,"rollingCountSemaphoreRejected":0,"rollingCountShortCircuited":0,"rollingCountSuccess":1,"rollingCountThreadPoolRejected":0,"rollingCountTimeout":0,"currentConcurrentExecutionCount":0,"rollingMaxConcurrentExecutionCount":1,"latencyExecute_mean":0,"latencyExecute":{"0":0,"25":0,"50":0,"75":0,"90":0,"95":0,"99":0,"99.5":0,"100":0},"latencyTotal_mean":0,"latencyTotal":{"0":0,"25":0,"50":0,"75":0,"90":0,"95":0,"99":0,"99.5":0,"100":0},"propertyValue_circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold":20,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds":5000,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage":50,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceOpen":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerForceClosed":false,"propertyValue_circuitBreakerEnabled":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationStrategy":"SEMAPHORE","propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds":60000,"propertyValue_executionTimeoutInMilliseconds":60000,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadInterruptOnTimeout":true,"propertyValue_executionIsolationThreadPoolKeyOverride":null,"propertyValue_executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":100,"propertyValue_fallbackIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests":10,"propertyValue_metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds":10000,"propertyValue_requestCacheEnabled":true,"propertyValue_requestLogEnabled":true,"reportingHosts":1,"threadPool":"RibbonCommand"}
```

Comment: There's a comment in the source code that suggests it's intentional: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/route/RestClientRibbonCommand.java#L91

Comment: @Dave Syer... can i override that and also can that be the the reason I am not seeing the Thread pool in my hystrix dashboard.. I have asked the question about thread pool in my previous question.,...

Comment: If there is no thread pool that would certainly explain why there is nothing in the UI. What did you try to override it? It looks like probably if you know the command key you can set the config key. But why would you want to?

Answer (score 2):

`zuul.ribbonIsolationStrategy=THREAD`

You can use above command to force the ZUUL to use the THREAD strategy

Answer (score 1):

> Why is zuul forcing the isolation strategy for hystrix to be SEMAPHORE

See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/f3deb04521c8c0a0b6d9923b0b37d8673cb7fa0b/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/route/support/AbstractRibbonCommand.java#L85.

> // we want to default to semaphore-isolation since this wraps
>   
>   // 2 others commands that are already thread isolated